# PWA `beforeinstallprompt` not being fired on Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android-webview, progressive-web-apps

I created a PWA, display an install page if the app is not installed.

Install page contains an install button, `beforeinstallprompt` event handler enables the install button.

It is working fine and able to install **if I open it from the chrome installed on the phone**.

I shared the app URL by Facebook Messenger, and the browser opened by Facebook Messenger doesn't fire `beforeinstallprompt` event. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent) says `beforeinstallprompt` works on webView.

Is there anything else needed to work on webView?
Here is my code

```
window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('btnInstall').disabled = false;
  deferedEvent = e;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Progressive Web Apps in 2020](https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-in-2020-c15018c9931c#:%7E:text=You%20can%20not%20install%20PWAs%20from%20Facebook%20Mobile%20Browser%2C%20Firefox%20Preview%2C%20WebViews%2C%20Custom%20Tabs%20or%20Chrome%20for%20DayDream%20(VR%20mode).) it won't work.

> You can not install PWAs from Facebook Mobile Browser, Firefox Preview, WebViews, Custom Tabs or Chrome for DayDream (VR mode).

Comment: So what is the alternative to "beforeinstallprompt"?